# CUPS-PDF fails with [STATUS] PDF creation failed

Tags: linux, centos7, network-printer, cups, ghostscript

Hello I'm trying to set up CUPS-PDF on a new server (Centos 7) but don't get it working.

I see the jobs reported.
[image: CUPS interface]

Also directories are being created according to conf file.
But there are no pdf created and the log file shows for each job only

[STATUS] PDF creation failed

Please advise what should be the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without deep understanding why and after many different actions without success I finally tried:

yum remove cups-pdf

yum install cups-pdf

And everyting works wel as intended...